# pyinotify methods not called

Tags: python, linux, inotify, pyinotify

I want to create a module that will watch for folder. I write some of code:

```
import os, pyinotify

class FileWatcher:
    def start_watch(self, dir):
        wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
        self.notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, EventProcessor())
        mask = pyinotify.IN_CREATE | pyinotify.IN_MODIFY | pyinotify.IN_DELETE | pyinotify.IN_DELETE_SELF | pyinotify.IN_MOVED_FROM | pyinotify.IN_MOVED_TO
        wdd = wm.add_watch(dir, mask, rec=True)
        while True:
            self.notifier.process_events()
            if self.notifier.check_events():
                self.notifier.read_events()

    def stop_watch(self):
        self.notifier.stop()
        print ('\nWatcher stopped')

class EventProcessor(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        print('in CREATE')

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print('in MODIFY')

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
        print('in delete')

    def process_IN_DELETE_SELF(self, event):
        print('in delete self')

    def process_IN_MOVED_FROM(self, event):
        print('in MOVED_FROM')

    def process_IN_MOVED_TO(self, event):
        print('in IN_MOVED_TO')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    watcher = FileWatcher()
    try:
        folder = "/home/user/Desktop/PythonFS"
        watcher.start_watch(folder)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        watcher.stop_watch()
```

When i modified a file and then removed it the methods process_IN_MODIFY and process_IN_DELETE was never called. How cat i solve it?

But when i create a file the method process_IN_CREATE() was called.

OS is Linux mint 13.

**UPD: New Code**

Comment: Umm, this code isn't syntactically valid (indentation is missing, just paste it, select it, and press `Ctrl+K`), and it only defines classes and functions, and does not call any of them.

Comment: It's syntatically vallid code..
Methods should called from notifier, because i put Instance of EventProcessor to constructor of pyinotify.Notifier(...)

Comment: [No it's not](http://ideone.com/NJGsub). And why there are some callable functions in there, the code doesn't actually call them.

Comment: oh sorry. Parser of code works bad. And ctrl+k doesn't help to me.
I changed this line.

Comment: stop_watch and start_watch called from another module.It simple start and stop. I think they are not touching my problem.

Comment: If so, you should be able to reproduce the problem with a [simplified version](http://sscce.org/). If the problem only occurs when you're calling the start/stop functions from another module, you need to post that module.

Comment: I posted new code with same problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It is basically the same as your code; I've only added

```
f = FileWatcher()
f.start_watch('/tmp/test', None)
```

at the end to start a `FileWatcher`. Make sure the directory `/tmp/test` exists, or else change that line to point to an existent directory.

If a file `foo` exists in `/tmp/test`, and if I modify this file,
the above program prints

```
in create   # after modification
in modify   # after saving
in modify
in delete
```

Now if I delete the file, the program prints:

```
in delete
```

---

```
import os
import pyinotify


class FileWatcher:
    notifier = None

    def start_watch(self, dir, callback):
        wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
        self.notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, EventProcessor(callback))
        mask = (pyinotify.IN_CREATE | pyinotify.IN_MODIFY | pyinotify.IN_DELETE
                | pyinotify.IN_DELETE_SELF | pyinotify.IN_MOVED_FROM
                | pyinotify.IN_MOVED_TO)
        wdd = wm.add_watch(dir, mask, rec=True)
        while True:
            self.notifier.process_events()
            if self.notifier.check_events():
                self.notifier.read_events()


class EventProcessor(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.event_callback = callback

    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        # if self.event_callback is not None:
        # self.event_callback.on_file_created(os.path.join(event.path,
        # event.name))
        print('in create')

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        # if self.event_callback is not None:
        # self.event_callback.on_file_modifed(os.path.join(event.path,
        # event.name))
        print('in modify')

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
        print('in delete')

    def process_IN_DELETE_SELF(self, event):
        print('in delete self')

    def process_IN_MOVED_FROM(self, event):
        print('in moved_from')

    def process_IN_MOVED_TO(self, event):
        print('in moved to')


f = FileWatcher()
f.start_watch('/tmp/test', None)
```

---

By the way, once you call `f.start_watch`, the process falls into a `while True` loop from which it can not escape. Even calling `f.stop_watch` from another thread will not somehow break you out of this while loop.

If you do plan on using threading, you may need to pass a `threading.Event` to `start_watch`, and check its state inside the `while-loop` to determine when to break out of the loop.